# Running many node js applications as single instance

Tags: node.js

I'm using express framework to run many node applications basically as different node instances. Is it possible to run all the applications as single node instance (like routing with different url and same port) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure:

```
var express = require('express');

var main    = express();
var app1    = express();
var app2    = express();

main.use(app1);
main.use(app2);

app1.get('/app1/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send('handled by app1');
});

app2.get('/app2/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send('handled by app2');
});

main.listen(3012);
```

If each app has their own unique URL prefix, you can also use this:

```
var express = require('express');

var main    = express();
var app1    = express();
var app2    = express();

main.use('/app1', app1);
main.use('/app2', app2);

app1.get('/test', function(req, res) { // GET /app1/test
  res.send('handled by app1');
});

app2.get('/test', function(req, res) { // GET /app2/test
  res.send('handled by app2');
});

main.listen(3012);
```